# full path in breadcrumbs wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, schema, breadcrumbs

I want to take a full path in bread crumbs in the wordpress template

Now displays only the home page and category

I want the home - category - the title of the article with the link to this page, with a working schema markup

now the code looks like this
version Wordpress 4.8.1

```
function barcelona_breadcrumb() {
    if ( barcelona_get_option( 'show_breadcrumb' ) != 'on' ) {
        return;
    }
    $barcelona_post_type = is_single() ? get_post_type() : NULL;
    $barcelona_sep_icon = '';
    $barcelona_items = '';
    if ( ( is_single() && $barcelona_post_type == 'post' && ! is_attachment() ) || is_category() ) {
        $barcelona_categories = is_category() ? array() : get_the_category();
        $barcelona_current_cat = $barcelona_last_cat = is_category() ? get_queried_object() : $barcelona_categories[0];
        $barcelona_counter = 3;
        while ( $barcelona_current_cat->category_parent != '0' ) {
            $barcelona_current_cat = get_category( $barcelona_current_cat->category_parent );
            $barcelona_items = $barcelona_sep_icon .'<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="'. esc_url( get_category_link( $barcelona_current_cat ) ) .'"><span itemprop="name">'. esc_html( $barcelona_current_cat->name ) .'</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="%'. $barcelona_counter .'%" /></li>'. $barcelona_items;
            $barcelona_counter++;
        }
        $barcelona_items .= $barcelona_sep_icon .'<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><'. ( is_category() ? 'span' : 'a href="'. esc_url( get_category_link( $barcelona_last_cat ) ) .'"' ) .' itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">'. esc_html( $barcelona_last_cat->name ) .'</span></'. ( is_category() ? 'span' : 'a' ) .'><meta itemprop="position" content="%2%" /></li>';
            if ( $barcelona_counter > 3 ) {
            $barcelona_arr = array_reverse( range( 2, $barcelona_counter - 1 ) );
            foreach( $barcelona_arr as $k => $v ) {
                $barcelona_items = str_replace( 'itemprop="position" content="%'. intval( $k + 2 ) .'%"', 'itemprop="position" content="'. intval( $v ) .'"', $barcelona_items );
            }
        } else {
            $barcelona_items = str_replace( 'content="%2%"', 'content="2"', $barcelona_items );
        }
    } else if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) {
        $barcelona_title = is_search() ? esc_html__( 'Search Results', 'barcelona' ) : esc_html( get_the_archive_title() );
        if ( is_author() ) {
            $barcelona_title = esc_html__( 'Author Archive', 'barcelona' );
        } else if ( is_year() ) {
            $barcelona_title = esc_html__( 'Yearly Archive', 'barcelona' );
        } else if ( is_month() ) {
            $barcelona_title = esc_html__( 'Monthly Archive', 'barcelona' );
        } else if ( is_day() ) {
            $barcelona_title = esc_html__( 'Daily Archive', 'barcelona' );
        } else if ( is_tag() ) {
            $barcelona_title = esc_html__( 'Tag Archive', 'barcelona' );
        }
        $barcelona_items .= $barcelona_sep_icon .'<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">'. $barcelona_title .'</span></span><meta itemprop="position" content="2" /></li>';
    }
    $barcelona_items = '<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. esc_html__( 'Home', 'barcelona' ) .'</a><meta itemprop="position" content="1" /></li>'. $barcelona_items;
        echo '<div class="breadcrumb-wrapper"><div class="container"><ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumb">'. $barcelona_items .'</ol></div></div>';
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code put below code in functions.php

```
function the_breadcrumbs() {

    global $post;

    if (!is_home()) {

        echo "<a href='";
        echo get_option('home');
        echo "'>";
        echo "Site's name here";
        echo "</a>";

        if (is_category() || is_single()) {

            echo " > ";
            $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );

            foreach ( $cats as $cat ){
                echo $cat->cat_name;
                echo " > ";
            }
            if (is_single()) {
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {

            if($post->post_parent){
                $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                $anc_link = get_page_link( $post->post_parent );

                foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                    $output = " > <a href=".$anc_link.">".get_the_title($ancestor)."</a> > ";
                }

                echo $output;
                the_title();

            } else {
                echo ' > ';
                echo the_title();
            }
        }
    }
elseif (is_tag()) {single_tag_title();}
elseif (is_day()) {echo"Archive: "; the_time('F jS, Y'); echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_month()) {echo"Archive: "; the_time('F, Y'); echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_year()) {echo"Archive: "; the_time('Y'); echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_author()) {echo"Author's archive: "; echo'</li>';}
elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "Blogarchive: "; echo'';}
elseif (is_search()) {echo"Search results: "; }
}
```

Put below code in header.php

```
 if(function_exists('the_breadcrumbs')) the_breadcrumbs();
```